# Are there usually include_path/htaccess restrictions on hosts?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting, internal-server-error

My .htaccess file looks like this:

`php_value include_path "/home/username/public_html/site"`

and is the same location as the include path.

It's causing a 500 internal service error, but was working fine locally. I'm digging around to try and find something via the host but not having much luck.

Comment: This works only if PHP is loaded as an Apache module. Maybe that isn't the case.

Comment: hrm I guess that would seem likely; the host doesn't list much as far as technical specs like that. do you know of a similar htaccess based alternative? it was the only way I was able to get everything successfully included

Comment: Did you check your Apache error.log to check why 500 is being generated?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the exact error message, it is difficult to tell what is going wrong. As Pekka explained, one reason could be that mod_php is not used. This could be the case, for instance if suPHP or any other variant based on PHP's CGI interface is used.

If that's the case AND if you are using PHP 5.3.0 or later, you could create a per-directory configuration using a `.user.ini` file<sup>1</sup>. So instead of using a `.htaccess` file with the line

```
php_value include_path "/home/username/public_html/site"
```

you would use a `.user.ini` containing the line

```
include_path = "/home/username/public_html/site"
```

<sup>1</sup>) Note that this is the default file name. The file may have a different name (the file name is configured through the INI directive `user_ini.filename`) or may be *disabled* completely.

Comment: Thanx a lot, per directory php.ini file really helped. But in some cases it may not work when the server not allowing ini files in directories.

Answer (score 1):

In Centos, the default include_path is:

.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

Comment: Yes, default path is displaying. Need to add more paths, as the project need is like that. Neither ini_set nor the htaccess is working here.